# AES encryption for repetitive small data packets

Tags: encryption, aes, iot

I'm trying to implement simple AES encryption for small data packets (8bytes, fixed length) being sent from nodes with very little computational resources.

Ideally the encrypted data would be a single 16byte packet. The data being sent is very repetitive (for an example, wind velocity packet "S011D023", where S and D would always be in the same place, length would always be 8). The nodes may not have the ability to hold runtime variables (e.g. a frame counter, nonce etc.) but could be implemented if essential.

How do I make the solution "reasonably" secure against replay, brute force, any other well known attack? Does adding new random padding bytes to each new packet help in anyway?

Comment: There is a [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange site where this may be a better fit. You will probably need to firm up which *specific* threats you need to protect against.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks, I'll try to post there as well. At this moment I'm not sure about what _specific_ threats to guard against.

Comment: How often are the packets transfered? What is the transport protocol?

Comment: @Red.Wave Roughly once every 20 minutes, very rarely a bunch of packets one after another (say 5 packets in 3 minutes). We are using proprietary sub-ghz RF link.

Comment: AES wouldn't fit your needs I guess. You cannot encrypte every message individually; the repeated pattern is a major softspot. Only the S & D must be secured, unless 6 unused random bytes are padded; just let the repeated pattern intact(as plain text).

Comment: @Red.Wave I'm not sure if I understand correctly, you mean unused bytes should be random padded? What would be a better fit, if not AES?

Comment: The crypto forum mentioned in 1st comment is a better place to look for an answer. I just think (I may be wrong) AES is not good in the long run for your case. But again since the TX rate is low, risk of successful attack is reduced too. The extra bytes are needed to insert entropy to plain text and guard against attack. Constant pattern bytes should be off the encryption, because repetition is always a soft spot in cryptography.